# Customize Android CalendarView - Display DropdownMenu

Tags: java, android, drop-down-menu, calendar, element

I have a project where I use a CalendarView, the built in Calendar for android.

So, I'm facing some difficulties to achieve some specific tasks for this Calendar. And I really hope I can find the solution here on StackOverflow.

1. Is there any possible way of setting each day on a onClickListener?
2. If not, Then stop reading.

This is the problem I have:

I would like to display a dropdown menu from the selected day, with a few elements that the user can select. If the user select some element, than the state will change for the dropdown menu ONLY for the selected date i.e. if user click on 13/1 the dropdown should display 10 elements. If user select one value, "lunch", then the dropdown menu must change so if user click again only "lunch" and "delete" will appear, not the other 9 elements which were displayed from first user interaction.

The problem I have here, is that the dropdown menu is connected to ALL dates, so I believe I need a onClickListener for each date in the calendar, therefore I wonder if it is possible.

I have been struggling with using different libraries from the internet, especially from GitHub without any success so I hope there's a way of achieve this via the built-in calendar.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any possible way of setting each day on a onClickListener?

Yes.
Try this way, In your onClickListener,
1. You need calendar instance.

```
Calendar calInstance=Calendar.getInstance();
```

2. SimpleDateFormatter required.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

3. Create a Date Object

```
Date date = new Date();
```

4. Create string to store current date on each click listener.

```
String currentDate=sdf.format(date);
```

5. Perform your required operations on this currentDate that you have received.

Comment: Okey, I'm not sure what you mean there. I use CalendarView, and from that view I would like to set each of the date on a sort of "click listener" to display a dropdown menu for each date, a specific dropdown menu (different elements) depending on which date the user select. 

Do you think it's still possible to achieve this?